# JSTL - iterating through array of random integers - not displaying in webPage

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm trying to iterate through myList (array) of random generated integers using JSP/JSTL. 
My code snipet which generates and stores integers, is located in my servlet.

On the other hand,iterating through an arrayList of Strings (see code below) works perfectly but when i try it with arrays based on the same logic, my webpage just doesnt show any unordered list of my random integers.

thank you for helping me out

My Servlet

```
package be.intec.servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import be.intecbrussel.entities.Auto;

    @WebServlet("/JSTLServlet")
    public class JSTLServlet extends HttpServlet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private static final String VIEW = "WEB-INF/JSP/JSTL.jsp";

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(VIEW);

            //=======below is the code using Array=====================================
            int[] myList = new int[42];
            for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
                myList[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            }
            request.setAttribute("mylist", myList);

            //=======below is the code using ArrayList=====================================


            List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John", "Georges", "Kevin");

            request.setAttribute("names", names);

            dispatcher.forward(request, response);      
        }

    }
```

My jstl.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css">


<title>JSTL Expample</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Iterate through my array</h2>

    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="arrayVar" items="${myList}">

            <li>${arrayVar}</li>


        </c:forEach>

    </ul>
<!-- ================================================================================ -->

    <h2>Iterate through my arrayList</h2>

    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="name" items="${names}">

            <li>${name}</li>

        </c:forEach>
    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ServletsAndJSPExampleProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>IndexServlet</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

my index Servlet

```
package be.intec.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/IndexServlet")
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String VIEW = "/WEB-INF/JSP/index.jsp";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(VIEW);

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }


}
```

Output in Browser is :

Iterate through my array: 
// here it should be showing my random numbers

Iterate through my arrayList:
// work very well

- John
- Georges
- Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've used "`mylist`" as name in your Servlet, and want to fetch the list using `${myList}`. **The name is case-sensitive!**

Comment: Thank you, i noticed that and even though i'm aware of the case sensitiveness in jsp/jstl, i didnt thought it would be required in this particular case. Thank. My dumb mystake.

Answer (score 2):

Change your for each as shown below:

```
<c:forEach var="arrayVar" items="${mylist}">
<li>${arrayVar}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: That is another option indeed but i'll keep the myList orthography to respect the naming convention. Thank you for your help